# Poetry unable to install plenty of packages

Tags: dependency-management, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am trying to install the [pytorch3d](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d) library directly from Github via poetry. I noticed, however, that apparently this library is not PEP-517 compliant. It has a build-time dependency on torch but this dependency is not declared in the pyproject.toml file of the project. From what I understand, it is now a Python packaging best practice that libraries should specify their build dependencies explicitly.

The problem arises when I attempt to install this library via poetry, as poetry is very restrictive and simply fails to perform the installation. What I find concerning is that this happens very often with poetry, while in such cases pip has no issue to install the library whatsoever.

I start to assume that poetry is simply not suited for dependency management if the project involves a lot of non-standard, third-party, and potentially legacy, libraries. In a development workflow it is often not possible to only use dependencies that are totally up-to-date in PEP standards, hence I find that such restriction is a serious issue with poetry.

My questions:

- Is there any workaround to install such "problematic" packages?
- If I need to resort to using pip for such packages, would that mean the end of poetry's dependency resolution capabilities, since some of the packages would be installed via poetry and others via pip?
- Should I even use poetry at all, or would I be better off with something else?

Comment: I suggest you simply speak with the upstream project to release necessary binary wheels on PyPi and your problems mitigated. It sounds like a feature in pytorch3d packaging files that can be addressed by making it more robust.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, the problem is, pytorch3d developers do not want to make this change, and this is not the only library that I am unable to install with poetry, and reaching out to all the library developers and hope that they take action is not too realistic, I'm afraid.

Comment: If Pytorch3d developers do not want to support standard Python packaging, it is an unrealistic expectation any Python package installer outside what the library authors choose to support can install the package. However what you can is to install all other packages using Poetry and then after run a single `pip install` command to install unsupported packages.

Comment: You could argue that strictness in the Python package tooling (Poetry in this case) is what drives Python packaging ecosystem forward. -- In the meantime, if you can: build the wheels yourself (somehow) and store them locally in a wheelhouse or some internal PyPI-like repository. I also recommend using something like [_simpleindex_](https://github.com/uranusjr/simpleindex) to help with that.